# A question regarding approximation of multivariate functions as linear combinations of its partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have been reading a Wikipedia page, and there it says that any non linear n-dimensional differentiable function can be approximated as $$f(a,b,...)\approx f^0+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{a}}a+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{b}}b+~...~$$
Can anyone explain from where does this come from, and why it can't be applied to linear multivariate functions (which I assume are functions of following format $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=c+ax_1+b_x2+~...$) ? 
Also what does $f^0$ represent?

Comment: For a linear function the approximation derived here (it's just the first part of a multivariate Taylor expansion) is exactly the same as the original function.  So it's technically not an approximation.